# Sort on different date format(mmddyyyy) - xslt

Tags: sorting, date, xslt-3.0

I have a date field in XML which will always be in MMDDYYYY format. I am trying to sort using the date by the following code:

```
 <xsl:sort select="format-date(Date, '[M01][D01][Y0001]')"/>
```

Need help in resolving.
I have got a clue by calling a function within sort where we can convert this into ISO format. Can we ignore calling the function when Date field does not appear in some XML elements?

Following example shows the input XML as well as XSLT Code:

### Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmpD>
   <PR>
      <RType>02</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
   </PR>
   <PR>
      <RType>02</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
   </PR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <EDate>05012020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
      <Type>NC</Type>
      <EDate>05022019</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <EDate>05022020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <EDate>05012020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
      <Type>NC</Type>
      <EDate>05012020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
      <Type>NC</Type>
      <EDate>05032019</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
</EmpD>
```

### XSLT Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ab="test" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

<xsl:function name="ab:us-date-to-iso" as="xs:date">
   <xsl:param name="us-date" as="xs:string"/> <!-- format MMDDYYYY -->
   <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(replace($us-date, '(..)(..)(....)', '$3-$1-$2'))"/>
</xsl:function>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
 
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="EmpD">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
              <xsl:sort select="Emp"/>
              <xsl:sort select="RType"/>
              <xsl:sort select="ab:us-date-to-iso(EDate)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmpD>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
      <Type>NC</Type>
      <EDate>05022019</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <EDate>05012020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <EDate>05022020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <PR>
      <RType>02</RType>
      <Emp>888</Emp>
   </PR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
      <Type>NC</Type>
      <EDate>05032019</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <EDate>05012020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   <JR>
      <RType>01</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
      <Type>NC</Type>
      <EDate>05012020</EDate>
      <HR>1210148900</HR>
      <JobC>Test</JobC>
   </JR>
   
   <PR>
      <RType>02</RType>
      <Emp>889</Emp>
   </PR>
</EmpD>
```

Comment: XPath allows you to check e.g. `if (Date) then ... else ...` so it is rather easy to check whether a `Date` elements exists; it is not quite clear what `ignore` in the context of `xsl:sort` means, you will need to explain how you want to treat/sort elements not having a `Date` element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - So, basically, I have many nodes under the root like PR,JR,UR etc. All nodes are having fields RT which can be 01,02,03 etc along with Date which is in MMDDYYYY format. The exception is PR won't have Date field. I have to sort this by RT and Date

Comment: Please edit your question and show us some minimal but representative sample of input and wanted output. Did you integrate the suggestion from the answer to your previous question? Can you show us the existing code and explain whether you get an error or whether sorting doesn't give the order you want?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Either change the function to use `castable as xs:date` in an `if (condition) then exp1 else exp2` or make the `<xsl:sort select="ab:us-date-to-iso(EDate)"/>` use that `if` expression with e.g. `<xsl:sort select="if (EDate) then ab:us-date-to-iso(EDate) else ()"/>`.